# Handle a function after all items are dropped using Jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have three items being dragged and dropped using Jquery UI. Is it possible to show a hidden button after the user has dropped all three items in the correct places? In other words I need to check if all items have been dropped correctly. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't test this, but here we go:

```
// list with one entry for each item
var todo_list = {
    id1: false,
    id2: false,
    id3: false
};

// total number of items to be dropped by the user
var remaining = 3;

$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if (todo_list[this.id] === false) {
             todo_list[this.id] = true;
             remaining--;

             if (remaining === 0) {
                 do_something();
             } 
        }
    }
});
```

Inside the `drop` callback you should be able to access the `id` of the dropped item by using `this.id`.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me out!